# jquery: access variable inside onload event

Tags: jquery, variables, iframe, onload

I am trying to access and return the `result` variable created inside the load event:

```
function submit_form_with_file(form, link, file)
{
    var iframe = $('<iframe name="postiframe" id="postiframe" style="display: none" ></iframe>');
    //append the iframe to the html page
    $("body").append(iframe);
    result="";
    var form = $(form);
    ...
    form.submit();
    $(iframe).load(function ()
    {
        var body=window.frames[$(iframe).attr("name")].document.body;
        result=(body.textContent || body.innerText);
        alert(result);
    });
    return result;
}
```

When I do `return result`, I want two things: wait till my iframe has been loaded, then return the `result` variable inside the load event. How to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot return avalue from `load` callback as it is executed asynchronously, what you can do is to pass a callback which will be invoked when the load is completed.

```
function submit_form_with_file(form, link, file, loadCallback) {
    var iframe = $('<iframe name="postiframe" id="postiframe" style="display: none" />');
    // append the iframe to the html page
    $("body").append(iframe);
    result = "";
    var form = $(form);
    // ...
    form.submit();
    $(iframe).load(function () {
        var body = window.frames[$(iframe).attr("name")].document.body;
        result = (body.textContent || body.innerText);
        loadCallback(result);
    });
    return result;
}
```

then

```
submit_form_with_file(form, link, file, function (result) {
    //loading is completed, do something with result
})
```